# Mongoid Schema Design for Orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to figure out what would be better schema design for MongoDB/Mongoid/Rails Shopping Cart.

```
class User
  ...
  embeds_many :orders
end
```

**or**

```
class User
  ...
  has_many :orders
end
```

Trying to decide which would be better from the performance point of view. Would like to use `embeds_many`, however I'm not sure how would the query performance be if I wanted to list all orders on one page (e.g. in the admin interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest thing here is if you embed `orders`, then it can't have any other associations (other than its own embedded objects). So it can't, for instance, have_many `products`. It can't `belong_to` a `shipment`. Nothing. If you schema can handle this, then OK.

The second question is do you want to list all the `orders` independent of `users`? If yes, then you really shouldn't embed them. If you do, then you will be making a bunch of db calls and that slows down your page load. Heroku actually shut down my site (automatically) a few times because I did something like this and I was (unknowingly) trying to make hundreds of calls in one page load. I changed my code a little bit and it loaded much faster and without complaint.

So, I would say don't embed them. Logically, `orders` should be separate from `users`, as they aren't an intrinsic part of `users`.